# how does firebase track the data used for billing in realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know how firebase limits the 1gb usage in real time database... I wanted to know if I get 1gb every month or just 1gb for the whole project? If it for the whole projects can i delete the data to stay in the 1gb limit.

Comment: Those limits are _per project_. 1 GB is total usage irrespective of how long you use it.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Dharmaraj  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 GB free tier storage is *per project* irrespective of how long you use it. If you are on the Blaze plan you'll be charged [`$5 / GB`](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) if you exceed the 1 GB storage.